# how to create pop up window with hyperlink in asp

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, popupwindow

I am trying to create a popup window when clicked the hyperlink.  Currently, my hyperlink is opening the entire page which is huge and i would like to make like a pop up, smaller size. How can i do that?
Here is my code:

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "~/DET/Policy.Merket?ID={0}") %>' Target="_blank">POLICY</asp:HyperLink>

   </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

i come back just to post the solution in case someone needs:

```
`<asp:Hyperlink Runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "~/DET/Policy.Merket?ID={0}") %>' onclick="window.open (this.href, 'popupwindow',  'width=400,height=400,scrollbars,resizable'); return false;">Link text goes here<asp:Hyperlink>`
```

Comment: You can use window.open() look here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp for documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the javascript `window.open()` function in a pure HTML button. Copying from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp), you can see an example defining the popup window size etc.

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","_blank","toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");return false">Link text</a>
```

Another alternative would be to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and specifically the [overlay](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html) tool.

Hope I helped!

Comment: i was thinking something like window.open() method.  can someone please help?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the [ajaxtoolkit modalpopup](http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

it will much more helpfull for you

thanks,